# Automatically kill a process based on zise and timeout

Tags: microsoft-excel, matlab

I am using Matlab which is constantly generating ghost excel processes - our around 40 mb each and whcih refuse to close on their own (after Matlab request) - I wonder if there is a way to automatically kill such procesess:

Excel.exe (lower than 100 mbs)
open time - 20 seconds?

Comment: maybe batch script?

Comment: thank you but which program allos to set such contraints?

Comment: check this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98261-why-do-some-excel-processes-fail-to-terminate-after-using-xlsread-xlswrite-or-xlsfinfo-in-matlab) it may help. You would have to find a way to close only the 'lower than 100 mbs', but you could just type in Matlab `system('taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.EXE');` to close excel file

Comment: yes I tried this code - but it does nto work - does it kill the last process opened by Matlab and NOT the main excel file?